# What exactly is the session_hash?

Tags: shopify

I have a question regarding one of the shopify data elements.

During the web hook stage, I receive the orders data.

Inside this data, under the "client_details" section, there is a field called "session_hash".

I was wondering what kind of data is it (e.g. the session_id), and which hash function you use to generate it.

Answer (score 0):

The `session_hash` variable is a secure hash of the session id we use to identify individual customers (as you correctly surmise).

You can use it to identify a particular user session, but that's about it. You can't deconstruct the hash to obtain the original session id for obvious security reasons.

Comment: Rather than dsconstruct it, it would be useful to construct the session hash and then compare it with session_hash returned in the order API to identify a customer. For example, to track a conversion.